# Pentaho Data Integration Auto Create Date Created and Last Updated

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to create a job to insert all my data from `Mysql to MongoDB`

[image: pentaho]

and this is my configuration :

[image: configuration]

how to auto generate `date_created` and `last_updated`?

so every `data insert` will auto fill `date_created` to `new Date()` or current date time and every `data updated` will auto update field `last_updated` with `new Date()` or current date.

Comment: Seems that what you want is a DB Trigger, to create the date / timestamp of when that document was created, and another date / timestamp for when this document suffers an update. Correct ? If yes, then this can be achieved directly into MongoDB, not with pentaho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `Get System Info` step.

It gives you a number of variables realted to the environement, including the time of the run. I usually use the `system date (fixed)`, so that all the date-created are the same for the run, which ease retrieval.

For the `last_update`, it is that same technique, if you can setup your `Match field for update` in the `MongoDB output` step. If you cannot, have a look at the `Merge Row (diff)` : it tells you if the record is new, deleted, identical or changed.

[image]